# Converting an Oracle Query using LIKE to SQL Server Query

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I am converting an Application that is using an Oracle Database. In a part of the code
there is a condition (Below). In the ELSE, they are using the LIKE with '{0}%'.
The length of id in the database is always 8, so I don't understand why it is checking for a length of 10. So what happens is that if the user enters a valid id (12345678), it will always go to the ELSE. But I don't understand what the LIKE is actually doing. What would the conversion be for TSQL?

```
        if (id.Length == 10)
        {
            sb.Append("where job_id = :ID ");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("where job_id like '{0}%' order by job_id desc ", id);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`like` determines whether a specific character string matches a specified pattern. A pattern can include regular characters and wildcard.
so your query basically look at the id length , if it is 10 then it try to find the exact match
otherwise it looks for any job_id that starts with 0 ( looks like weird logic)

Comment: "otherwise it looks for any job_id that starts with 0" -- Nope, `{0}` is a place holder and is replace with the value of `id`. So in general it doesn't search for "any job_id that starts with 0" unless `id` is `0` of course.

Answer (score 0):

`sb` is a `StringBuilder` I believe? (You should always include such information in a question!) Then the arguments of `AppendFormat()` (for that given overload) are a format string and then an arbitrary number of parameters. To address the parameters in the format string their index enclosed in `{}` can be used. `{0}` is a place holder for the first parameter, `{1}` would be second and so on. So say if `id` is `123` for example `"where job_id like '123%' order by job_id desc` would be appended.

`LIKE` is an operator that compares two strings. The second operand can use wildcards -- in Oracle **and** SQL Server `%` is provided for any or zero arbitrary characters (including no character at all) or `_` for exactly one arbitrary character. For example `'ABCDEF' LIKE 'ABC%'` or `'ABCDED` LIKE '%CD%'` would be true. SQL Server allows some other patterns too but that aren't of concern here. So there's nothing to translate here, the expressions are valid in Oracle **and** SQL Server.

Now what the C# code does is appending `where job_id = :ID` to the string if `id`, which is a `string` I assume, has a length of 10 characters. Otherwise it appends `where job_id like '{0}%' order by job_id desc` where `{0}` is replaced with `id`'s value.

But the code is flawed. You should never insert values for SQL queries by using string concatenation or interpolation but always use parameters. So

```
sb.AppendFormat("where job_id like '{0}%' order by job_id desc ", id);
```

should really be something like

```
sb.Append("where job_id like concat(:ID, '%') order by job_id desc ");
```

(`concat()` concatenates the strings given to it. And of course that may require to change subsequent calls executing the query to provide a value for the parameter either way.)

I cannot judge if it makes sense to order the result only if the `id`'s length isn't 10 nor if it makes any sense to only search exactly for it if its length is 10 but for any value beginning with it otherwise because I don't know the reasoning behind it. But it certainly seems strange. Maybe the whole `if ... else ...` should simply be replaced by

```
sb.Append("where job_id like concat(:ID, '%') order by job_id desc ");
```

after all.

Comment: SQL Server parameters start with `@` not `:`